# Diferencia entre «entretuviesen» y «entretenieran»

Tags: diferencias-regionales, subjuntivo, conjugación, españa

Estoy experimentando con unos flashcards de [Anki](http://ankisrs.net/), y encontré esa frase:

> Si los niños se **entretuviesen** por unos minutos podría tomar una siesta.

Es la primera vez que he visto una conjugación así.  Según [wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/entretuviesen), esa es la forma *tercera persona del plural del subjuntivo imperfecto* del verbo "entretener".

Sin embargo, según [conjugacion.org](http://www.conjugation.org/cgi-bin/conj.php), la forma *tercera personal del plural del subjuntivo imperfecto* del verbo "entretener" es **entretenieran**.

Unos amigos españoles dicen que las dos formas pueden ser correctas, pero quizás la primera forma es más común en España.

Y wiktionary.com no dice nada de la segunda forma.

¿Hay otra diferencia entre las dos formas? ¿Es solo una cosa regional?  O quizás la segunda forma en realidad es incorrecta.

Answer (score 8):

Es cierto que hay dos formas, pero solo una de las que tienes en tu pregunta se admite.

*Entretener* viene del prefijo *entre* y la palabra base *tener*. Por eso, tiene las mismas irregularidades que tiene su base: *entretén* (del imp. *ten*), *entretengo* (de pres. ind. *tengo*), *entretendré* (de fut. ind. *tendré*), etcétera.

La flexión para la tercera persona plural del pretérito imperfecto del subjuntivo de *tener* es o *tuvieran* o *tuviesen* (recuerda que todos los verbos tienen mínimo dos formas intercambiables en este tiempo/modo). Por consiguiente las formas de *entretener* son **entretuvieran** y **entretuviesen**.

El único verbo en que puedo pensar que tiene flexiones regulares e irregulares en el pretérito imperfecto del subjuntivo es *placer* (que en la tercera persona plural existen *placieran*, *pluguieran*, *placiesen* y *pluguiesen*)

Comment: (Seguramente conjugacion.org está conjugando cualquier verbo como regular a menos que esté en algún listado de irregulares)

Comment: Definitivamente es un error del motor de conjucación.org porque en word reference si aparece correctamente http://www.wordreference.com/conj/EsVerbs.aspx?v=entretener

Answer (score 4):

"Entetenieran" esta totalmente incorrecto. Las únicas conjugaciones que se permiten en este caso son "entretuvieran" y "entretuviesen".

"Entretuvieran" es la forma mas común de decirlo en latinoamérica, y "entretuviesen" lo dicen mucho en España. Pero como decidas usarlo, ambos casos están bien y no hay diferencia entre ellos.